# Would like to convert complex Linq query to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

So I have a MS SQL database that I have been using exclusively with LINQ to Entities because I understand LINQ, not SQL. I'm toying around with the idea of learning more SQL and possibly using stored procs to speed things up. However, I have no clue on how to write the following in SQL so I'm looking at what LinqPad generates as a starting point.

The following query successfully gets the most popular titles based on how many times the title was "Queued" in a specific "Channel" or Channels in the last 7 days along with top 3 "Actors" of that title based on their Order.

```
var dateStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
var channels = new[] { 1 };

var query = (from p in TitleQueues
                    where p.QueueTime >= dateStart
                          && p.QueueTime <= dateNow
                    group p by p.TitleId
                    into grouped
                    from t in Titles
                    let cast = (from tc in t.TitlePeoples
                    from td in tc.TitlePersonTitlePeopleDepartments
                    where td.Department.Type == "Actors"
                    orderby tc.Order
                    select new { tc.Person.Name, tc.Person.Id }).Take(3)
                    where t.Id == grouped.Key
                    from g in t.TitleSources
                    where
                        channels.Contains(g.TitleProviderId) && g.AvailableFrom <= dateNow &&
                        g.AvailableTo >= dateNow
                        && t.Rank != null
                    orderby grouped.Count() descending , t.Rank
                    select new {
                        t.Id,
                        t.Name,
                        t.ReleaseYear,
                        t.ShortSynopsis,
                        t.TitleTypeId,
                        t.MPAARating,
                        t.Runtime,
                        t.IMDbTop250Rank,
                        t.CombinedRating,
                        cast
                    }).Take(10);

                    query.Dump();
```

This is the SQL LinqPad generates based on the above Linq query:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime2 = '2011-12-28 12:13:29.4306979'
DECLARE @p1 DateTime2 = '2012-01-04 12:13:29.4306979'
DECLARE @p2 Int = 1
DECLARE @p3 DateTime2 = '2012-01-04 12:13:29.4306979'
DECLARE @p4 DateTime2 = '2012-01-04 12:13:29.4306979'
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (10) [t2].[Id], [t2].[Name], [t2].[ReleaseYear], [t2].[ShortSynopsis], [t2].[TitleTypeId], [t2].[MPAARating], [t2].[Runtime], [t2].[IMDbTop250Rank], [t2].[CombinedRating]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[TitleId]
    FROM [TitleQueues] AS [t0]
    WHERE ([t0].[QueueTime] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[QueueTime] <= @p1)
    GROUP BY [t0].[TitleId]
    ) AS [t1]
CROSS JOIN [Titles] AS [t2]
CROSS JOIN [TitleSources] AS [t3]
WHERE ([t3].[TitleProviderId] IN (@p2)) AND ([t3].[AvailableFrom] <= @p3) AND ([t3].[AvailableTo] >= @p4) AND ([t2].[Rank] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[Id] = [t1].[TitleId]) AND ([t3].[TitleId] = [t2].[Id])
ORDER BY (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [TitleQueues] AS [t4]
    WHERE ([t1].[TitleId] = [t4].[TitleId]) AND ([t4].[QueueTime] >= @p0) AND ([t4].[QueueTime] <= @p1)
    ) DESC, [t2].[Rank]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Actors'
DECLARE @x1 Int = 130323
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (3) [t3].[Name], [t3].[Id]
FROM [TitlePeople] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [TitlePeopleDepartments] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN [People] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[Type] = @p0) AND ([t0].[TitleId] = @x1) AND ([t1].[TitlePersonId] = [t0].[Id])
ORDER BY [t0].[Order]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Actors'
DECLARE @x1 Int = 127948
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (3) [t3].[Name], [t3].[Id]
FROM [TitlePeople] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [TitlePeopleDepartments] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN [People] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[Type] = @p0) AND ([t0].[TitleId] = @x1) AND ([t1].[TitlePersonId] = [t0].[Id])
ORDER BY [t0].[Order]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Actors'
DECLARE @x1 Int = 90578
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (3) [t3].[Name], [t3].[Id]
FROM [TitlePeople] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [TitlePeopleDepartments] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN [People] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[Type] = @p0) AND ([t0].[TitleId] = @x1) AND ([t1].[TitlePersonId] = [t0].[Id])
ORDER BY [t0].[Order]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Actors'
DECLARE @x1 Int = 129887
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (3) [t3].[Name], [t3].[Id]
FROM [TitlePeople] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [TitlePeopleDepartments] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN [People] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[Type] = @p0) AND ([t0].[TitleId] = @x1) AND ([t1].[TitlePersonId] = [t0].[Id])
ORDER BY [t0].[Order]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Actors'
DECLARE @x1 Int = 130546
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (3) [t3].[Name], [t3].[Id]
FROM [TitlePeople] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [TitlePeopleDepartments] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN [People] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[Type] = @p0) AND ([t0].[TitleId] = @x1) AND ([t1].[TitlePersonId] = [t0].[Id])
ORDER BY [t0].[Order]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Actors'
DECLARE @x1 Int = 121981
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (3) [t3].[Name], [t3].[Id]
FROM [TitlePeople] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [TitlePeopleDepartments] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN [People] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[Type] = @p0) AND ([t0].[TitleId] = @x1) AND ([t1].[TitlePersonId] = [t0].[Id])
ORDER BY [t0].[Order]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Actors'
DECLARE @x1 Int = 121957
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (3) [t3].[Name], [t3].[Id]
FROM [TitlePeople] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [TitlePeopleDepartments] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN [People] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[Type] = @p0) AND ([t0].[TitleId] = @x1) AND ([t1].[TitlePersonId] = [t0].[Id])
ORDER BY [t0].[Order]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Actors'
DECLARE @x1 Int = 125377
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (3) [t3].[Name], [t3].[Id]
FROM [TitlePeople] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [TitlePeopleDepartments] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN [People] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[Type] = @p0) AND ([t0].[TitleId] = @x1) AND ([t1].[TitlePersonId] = [t0].[Id])
ORDER BY [t0].[Order]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Actors'
DECLARE @x1 Int = 91239
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (3) [t3].[Name], [t3].[Id]
FROM [TitlePeople] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [TitlePeopleDepartments] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN [People] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[Type] = @p0) AND ([t0].[TitleId] = @x1) AND ([t1].[TitlePersonId] = [t0].[Id])
ORDER BY [t0].[Order]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = 'Actors'
DECLARE @x1 Int = 121903
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (3) [t3].[Name], [t3].[Id]
FROM [TitlePeople] AS [t0]
CROSS JOIN [TitlePeopleDepartments] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Departments] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t1].[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN [People] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[Type] = @p0) AND ([t0].[TitleId] = @x1) AND ([t1].[TitlePersonId] = [t0].[Id])
ORDER BY [t0].[Order]
```

So is this a good starting point for a stored procedure? If you were to write a proc for this, what would it look like?

Comment: First question: does the generated SQL return the same results as your LINQ expression?

Comment: Wow... That's one piece of a hard to understand LINQ statement. Good thing you understand LINQ. Imagine people who understands SQL, not LINQ. How much trouble will they have? Anyways, based on your question, the query return different results? I refer to your "OR" - tiles.. OR channels. Is that right?

Comment: @BobKaufman Yes, both queries return the same result.

Comment: @Schultz9999, Ha, that Linq makes perfect sense to me. It's a little different in my project but that's what it looks like in LinqPad. And yes, both queries return the exact same results.

Comment: Maybe it does what you want but I somehow expect it is a bad query. Once query contains `CROSS JOIN` I'm always suspicious. Also I wonder how is it possible that it produced so many queries. I have never seen EF to convert single linq-to-entities query to mare than one SQL query.

Comment: Ok, now I see that. Your `let cast =` produces a new query for every title. That is really awful query. How many records do you expect to have in database?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Lol, I know it's a bad query. I'll check out how to remove the Cross Joins to see if any improvements can be made. The Titles table has 42,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try using SQL Profiler to observe the actual SQL being sent to the database.
Perhaps this will provide a better starting point.

Comment: I did that, but the SQL generated from LinqPad is MUCH nicer, and readable, than what is sent from EF.